# Node Error on AWS Ubuntu instance from remote browser

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, express

I have an Amazon EC2 instance, Ubuntu. Here's my node example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello Express');
});
app.listen(8080, 'http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-x.compute.amazonaws.com');
```

The xx's are my actual address.

I start node in SSH, all is well.

I go to a browser on my laptop visit http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-x.compute.amazonaws.com
Node errors out (visiting same domain:8080 errors out too):

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

I do have an inbound rule for HTTP on 80 setup on this instance.

Comment: Try this: `app.listen(8080);`

Comment: Now there's no error, node continues to listen, but browser just says couldn't connect to ....

Comment: Do you visit `http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-x.compute.amazonaws.com:8080`?

Answer (score 1):

You are listening on port 8080 but have inbound rule for port 80. Add a new rule on AWS EC2 console for port 8080.

Also, as suggested, just do `app.listen(8080)`

If you want the server to run on port 80, do `app.listen(80)`. But you will have to run the process as super user. So `sudo node app.js`

Comment: After correcting the other security group, I am doing app.listen(8080) instead now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying, actually, I solved the problem.

I have two instances and they are in a different order than the order of my security groups for those instances...I setup a rule on port 80 for the other security group (the correct one) and it works now.